# How to prove this function is a kernel?

Tags: machine-learning

Here I have a function $k(x,y) = (1+xy)^n$, then how to prove this function is a kernel on $\mathbb{R}$ space?

Comment: it's polynomial kernel

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
(1+xy)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(xy)^i = \sum_{i=0}^n \left[\binom{n}{i}^\frac12x^i \right]\left[\binom{n}{i}^\frac12y^i \right]
\end{align}

Hence we can see that $x$ is being mapped to an $(n+1)$-dimensional feature space and the expression above can be viewed as an inner product.

Comment: Thanks, but how to prove the Gram matrix is positive semi-definite?

Comment: proof on [page 2](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/rmittal/prev_course/s14/notes/lec11.pdf)